# Can I force LibreOffice basic to report an error for undefined variables?

Tags: undefined, libreoffice-basic

Just as the title says: can I force LibreOffice basic to report an error for undefined variables? I am so used to sane languages that I keep blundering into this: when I misspell a variable, LibreOffice just creates it with an initial value.

Ideally I would like to force this in one place for all macros I use in documents I create. If that is not possible, what is the most reliable and least onerous way to force it?

*I have realised the basic answer is quite straightforward – one might say Check the Fing Manual – and I provide it below – but this has caused me enough grief that it seems worth documenting here*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this per module:

- Add `Option Explicit` at the start of every module you write. For details, see the LibreOffice help under [Macros and Programming – Using Variables – Forcing Variable Declarations](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/01020100.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=UNIX) (link for version 6.1).

I *think* that: no, you cannot do it for all your documents and modules in one place:(